# Undefined index when accessing an array index

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to modify a user counter code, that prints a message stored in an array. The visitor counter is taken as the array index

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

$age = array("url1","url2","url3");
// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}
// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);
$counterVal++;
$f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
fwrite($f, $counterVal);
fclose($f); 

echo "hi Hello";
echo $counterVal;   
$me = $age[$counterVal];
echo $me;
?>
```

But I get the following error,

```
hi Hello1
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 1
 in xxx/glob.php on line 23
```

what can be the possible error as `index 1` has a value asociated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Better code for do that:

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";
$age = array("url1","url2","url3");
$counterVal = file_exists($counter_name)?
    (int)file_get_contents($counter_name)++:
    0;
file_put_contents($counter_name, $counterVal);

echo "hi Hello";
echo $counterVal;   
$me = $age[$counterVal];
echo $me;
```

?>

Comment: If even your code works fine, it's not clear, what you have changed and why OP code don't work